# Difficult case statement formulation

Tags: sql, hive

I have user tracking data for user input for two tools, where users can input data within "Inputs" page and/or "Results" page.

I would like to do an average age by user_id by page, ie. `avg(age) over (partition by user_id, page_name)`, but in it's current form there is often duplication between `Inputs` and `Results`, so I would like it cleaned up before averaging.

(simplified) Snippet of current form:

```
page_name   page_type   user_id   age
Tool 2      Inputs      2174246   53
Tool 2      Inputs      2174246   50
Tool 2      Results     2174246   53
Tool 1      Inputs      2425226   65
Tool 1      Results     2425226   65
Tool 1      Results     2425226   50
Tool 2      Inputs      2427115   50
Tool 2      Results     2427115   55
Tool 1      Results     620071    65
Tool 2      Inputs      2427536   55
```

Here is what I am thinking (by user id and tool), but don't know how to write it:

```
case when Results age = Inputs age then return Results age  
when Results age is not null and Inputs age is null then return Results age          
when Inputs age is not null and Results age is null then return Inputs age       
when Results age is not null and Inputs age is not null then return each
```

The case statement should take care of all scenarios unless I missed something, resulting in:

```
select user_id, page_name, avg(case statement for age) over (partition by user_id, page_name) as age

page_name   user_id   age
Tool 2      2174246   51.5
Tool 1      2425226   67.5
Tool 2      2427115   52.5
Tool 1      620071    65
Tool 2      2427536   55
```

Data is in Hive, but SQL should work here as well.

Thank you in advance for the assistance!

Comment: Your case statement runs before partitioning, which makes whole construction useless. Try to separate statements for results and inputs, should be easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would seem to want:

```
select user_id, page_name, avg(age) as age
from (select distinct user_id, page_num, age
      from t
     ) t
group by user_id, page_num;
```

Comment: It is pretty hilarious how right you are. The example is abit simplified, can you assist with making this work for multiple dates? ie. say I have a date field, if someone inputs the same value in 2 different days, it shouldn't be excluded, only if multiple values in same day.

Comment: @user8834780 . . . Ask another question with appropriate sample data and desired results.